# blackboard italic font

Tags: fonts, math-mode, italic

I would like to make `\mathbb{E}` italic, i have tried `\mathit{\mathbb{E}}` and `\mathbb{\mathit{E}}`, both of them look like `\mathbb{E}`, I can not see the italic effect. Could anyone help?

By the way, I do see some blackboard italic words in a paper, so it is realizable in LaTeX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbmsl}{U}{bbm}{m}{sl}
```

in your preamble and use `\mathbbmsl{A}` to get an A as "blackboard bold slanted". There's no Type1 version of the font, though, so a bitmap will be generated.