# Free, non-upright, blackboard, Type1 font

Tags: fonts, symbols, blackboard

Is there a free package to get non-upright (i.e. italic or slanted) blackboard symbols in a Type1 font?

It's easy to get three of the four properties (i.e. [blackboard italic font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16645/blackboard-italic-font), http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html), but I failed to find a package with all four properties combined.
If there is some alternative to blackboard which also looks like a set symbol it would be fine, too.

Comment: It is also possible to use `mf2pt1` or `metatype1` utilities to convert MetaFont sources of `bbmsl` fonts to PostScript Type1 fonts. However, I have no any experience about it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. As your answer below completely fits my needs, I didn't test those, but thanks for pointing me to additional ressources if my needs grow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use fake slanted font by coordinate transformations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\fakeslant[1]{%
  \pdfliteral{1 0 0.167 1 0 0 cm}#1\pdfliteral{1 0 -0.167 1 0 0 cm}}
\newcommand\mathbbsl[1]{\mathbb{\fakeslant{#1}}}
\begin{document}

$\mathbbsl{ABC}$

\end{document}
```

pdfTeX or LuaTeX is required.

[image]

For latex+dvipdfmx or XeTeX, you can use `\special{pdf: literal ...}` instead of `\pdfliteral{...}`. i.e.

```
\newcommand\fakeslant[1]{%
  \special{pdf: literal 1 0 0.167 1 0 0 cm}#1\special{pdf: literal 1 0 -0.167 1 0 0 cm}}
```

Comment: Clever solution. A minor issue is that, e.g., with $\mathbbsl{H}'$ and $\mathbbsl{H}^\dagger$, the apostrophe and dagger seem too close to H. Can this be fixed? Thanks.