# Looking for upright calligraphic L with little loop on top

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for a calligraphic / script letter L with a little loop on the top.

`\mathcal{L}` from `amsfonts` doesn't have the little loop:

[image]

`\mathscr{L}` from `mathrsfs` has a loop, but it is too slanted for my taste:

[image]

I'm looking for a version where the vertical line is very straight, and there is a (small) loop on the top. Can anyone recommend a package or font?

Comment: In [this link](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/mathalfa.pdf) you can see many fonts, look if there is any that fits your needs.

Comment: @Manuel: Thanks for the link! Mathtime Pro 2 looks like what I'm looking for, unfortunately it's not free.

Comment: Then [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44934/free-non-upright-blackboard-type1-font/44935#44935) may probably help you, but if you “*unslant*” a lot, you need to take care of the surrounding spaces.

Comment: I tried [something very similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289439/how-do-i-fake-slanted-text-in-latex), but the version you linked to is nicer since it doesn't need Tikz. I have to play around with it a bit.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239791/is-this-laplace-transform-symbol-available-in-latex

Answer (score 9):

You can access a less-slanted calligraphic "L" by loading the [mathalfa](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalfa) package with the option `scr=rsfso` and typing `\mathscr{L}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=rsfso]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{L}$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*" As @Dan has pointed out, the same result may be achieved by loading the `rsfso` package with the option `scr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{L}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: For a minimal solution, use just the package `rsfso`. Load it without options to get the rsfso font for `\mathcal`. Load it with the option `[scr]` to keep the old `\mathcal` and add a new `\mathscr` command to produce the rsfso font.