# Is This Laplace Transform Symbol Available in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I would like to use the Laplace transform symbol that appears in unicode (SCRIPT CAPITAL L U+2112)

[image: Laplace Unicode]

However, I could only find the following two symbols can be used for Laplace transforms:

[image: mathcal and mathscr]

There are other symbols provided by the [`math-unicode`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math?lang=en), but it seems that it does not work with `pdflatex`.

Any suggestions if a unicode-like symbol is available?

Comment: What is wrong with `\mathscr{L}` (script capital L)?

Comment: I find it ugly (too slanted)!

Comment: You will find many pdfLaTeX fonts here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here, I use Bruno's `\slantbox` from [Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188) in conjunction with `\mathscr`.

EDITED to use John K's variant of `\slantbox` at [Adjust custom made upright greek letters when used in subscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236915/adjust-custom-made-upright-greek-letters-when-used-in-subscripts/239823#239823) in order to achieve better horizontal positioning within the `\slantbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newlength{\foodim}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \foodim=#1\wd\foobox
        \hskip \wd\foobox
        \hskip -0.5\foodim
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
        \hskip 0.5\foodim
}}
\def\Laplace{\slantbox[-.45]{$\mathscr{L}$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Laplace\{\sin(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one needs it to be able to scale down to `\scriptscriptstyle`, then this approach will work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,scalerel}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newlength{\foodim}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \foodim=#1\wd\foobox
        \hskip \wd\foobox
        \hskip -0.5\foodim
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
        \hskip 0.5\foodim
}}
\def\Laplace{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[-.45]{$\SavedStyle\mathscr{L}$}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Laplace\{\sin(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} \quad\scriptscriptstyle
\Laplace\{\sin(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What a nice trick!

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `rsfso` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}

\newcommand{\Laplace}{\mathscr{L}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Laplace\{\sin(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Variant preamble if you need also `mathrsfs` (but in that case I'd simply use the script L provided by `\mathscr{L}`):

```
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\let\RSFSmathscr\mathscr  % save the meaning of \mathscr
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
\let\RSFSOmathscr\mathscr % save the new meaning of \mathscr
\let\mathscr\RSFSmathscr  % restore the previous meaning

\newcommand{\Laplace}{\RSFSOmathscr{L}}
```

Comment: For some reason this did not work for me. Maybe package conflicts.

Comment: @jak123 Are you loading `mathrsfs` or similar?

Comment: Yes I'm loading `mathrsfs`.

Comment: @jak123 Added. But you shouldn't use two different script alphabets.

Comment: There seems to be another problem. When I used your MWE's, I'm getting: `PK font rrsfso10 could not be created.` BTW, why is the `@egreg` tagging not working with me?

Comment: @jak123 Update your TeX distribution. The tagging isn't needed for reaching the message owner, so the system removes it automatically.

Comment: I'm using MikTeX 2.9 (updated today), still not working. I'm giving up and reverting back to @steven-b-segletes solution. Thanks for your help anyway. I still appreciate any thoughts on how to fix this.