# Does anyone know how I can get this symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, math-fonts

I found it in my differential equations book but I can't seem to get it to work. The only things that look close are `\mathscr{L}` and `\mathcal{L}`.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239791/is-this-laplace-transform-symbol-available-in-latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/172164) to get started finding maths symbols.

Comment: It's different than that one.

Comment: That identifier can't find this symbol

Comment: I would guess that is actually a \mathcal{L} or \mathscr{L}, but from a different math font. You can try to compare with one of [these fonts](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calligraphic/script math glyphs are intended to appear handwritten, so there is a lot of variation between fonts, just like with handwriting in real life.

To add to the other answers and comments:

In Unicode, Laplace transform is in the Letterlike block (at U+2112) and the bold script capital L version is in the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block (at U+1D4DB), so using `unicode-math` package and system fonts, a sampling of system math fonts looks like this:

[image: cal L plain and bold]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\usepackage{accents}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Colour=blue]
%\setmathfontface\mxits{XITS Math}
\setmathfontface\masana{Asana Math}
\setmathfontface\mdejavu{DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mtgdeja{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mpagella{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfontface\mbonum{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\setmathfontface\mschola{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfontface\mtermes{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfontface\mlatin{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfontface\mcambria{Cambria Math}
\setmathfontface\mfira{Fira Math}
\setmathfontface\mfreeserif{FreeSerif}
\setmathfontface\mlibert{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfontface\mnoto{Noto Sans Symbols}
\setmathfontface\mqui{Quivira}
\setmathfontface\mstixtwo{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfontface\mstixgen{STIXGeneral}
\setmathfontface\msymbola{Symbola}
\setmathfontface\mgaramond{\detokenize{Garamond-Math}}
\newcommand\mfsize{\Huge}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}


\newcommand\themassym{ℒ}%
\begin{document}
\section*{Sampling {\mfsize $\themassym $}}

\vspace{24pt}


\begin{tabular}{rccl}
XITS Math & \mfsize $\themassym$ & \mfsize $\mcambria \themassym$ & Cambria Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Asana Math & \mfsize $\masana {\themassym}$ & \mfsize $\mfira \themassym$ & Fira Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mdejavu \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mfreeserif \themassym$ & FreeSerif \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Bonum Math & \mfsize $\mbonum \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mlibert \themassym$ & Libertinus Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mtgdeja \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mnoto \themassym$ & Noto Sans Symbols \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Pagella Math & \mfsize $\mpagella \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mqui \themassym$ & Quivira \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Schola Math & \mfsize $\mschola \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mstixtwo \themassym$ &STIX Two Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Termes Math & \mfsize $\mtermes \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mgaramond \themassym$ & Garamond-Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Latin Modern Math & \mfsize $\mlatin \themassym$ & \mfsize $\msymbola \themassym$ & Symbola \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Kudos for the examples.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite the same, but `dutchcal` has a comparatively close glyph:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

        \usepackage{dutchcal}

        \begin{document}%
        $ \begin{array}[t]{c@{\quad}c}
         \small \verb+ \mathcal + & \small\verb+ \mathbcal + \\[6pt]
             \mathcal{L} & \mathbcal{L}
            \end{array} $

        \end{document}
```

[image]