# Inconsolata italics?

Tags: fonts, italic, fancyvrb

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975828/how-to-specify-non-standard-font-in-fancyvrb-verbatim/ for the start of this discussion.

I am using `fancyvrb` to create a fancy `Verbatim` environment. I have

```
\usepackage{inconsolata}
```

to load the Inconsolata font, then

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOut}
  {Verbatim}{fontfamily=zi4,fontsize=\relsize{-1}}
```

for the environment itself. I would like it to display in italics, but it appears the `inconsolata` package doesn't load an italicized version of that font. Is there some other package that does, or some other way I can get it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's no italic version of Inconsolata, I'm afraid.

Comment: Reference: [Inconsolata](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/inconsolata/) in the LaTeX Font Catalogue only shows `\normalfont`.

Answer (score 11):

The font Inconsolata does not have an italic or slanted variant (June 2014).

Some TeX engines can fake a slanted font, based on a font transformation feature of the PDF format (therefore PDF mode only).

### LuaTeX/XeTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[
  AutoFakeSlant,
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant},
]{Inconsolatazi4}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Regular
\textbf{Bold}
\textsl{Slanted}
\textit{Italics}
\textbf{\textsl{BoldSlanted}}
\textbf{\textit{BoldItalics}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The slanted/italic versions are only faked. Also the italics correction is not set.

### pdfTeX

A `SlantFont` operator can be used in the `.map` file.

The following Perl script `zi4-sl.pl` reads `zi4.map` (found via `kpsewhich`) and modifies the entries:

- `-sl` is added to the font (TFM) name,
- `.167 SlantFont` is added.

Perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
$^W=1;

my $outfile = 'zi4-sl.map';
my $infile = `kpsewhich zi4.map`;
chomp $infile;

open(IN, '<', $infile) or die "!!! Error: Cannot open `zi4.map': $!";
open(OUT, '>', $outfile) or die "!!! Error: Cannot write `$outfile': $!";

while (<IN>) {                                                                  
    next if /^\s*$/;                                       
    s/^([^- ]+)-([^- ]+)/$1-$2-sl/ or die "!!! Error: Cannot parse TFM name!\n";
    s/ " / " .167 SlantFont / or die "!!! Error: Cannot insert SlantFont!\n";
} continue {
    print OUT;
}

close(IN);
close(OUT);
__END__
```

The following example:

- includes the map file via `\pdfmapfile`,
- defines the font shapes (would go into `.fd` files normally).

```tex
\pdfmapfile{+zi4-sl.map}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\makeatletter
\sbox0{\ttfamily x}% load .fd file
\expandafter\ifx\csname zifour@scaled\endcsname\relax
  \let\zifour@scaled\@empty
\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname zifour@opt\endcsname\relax
  \def\zifour@opt{\z@}\def\zifour@altopt{\tw@}
\fi
\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{zi4}{m}{sl}{%
  <-> \zifour@scaled ot1-zi4r-sl-\zifour@opt}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{zi4}{m}{it}{%
  <-> ssub * zi4/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{zi4}{b}{sl}{%
  <-> \zifour@scaled ot1-zi4b-sl-\zifour@opt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{zi4}{bx}{sl}{%
  <-> ssub * zi4/b/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{zi4}{b}{it}{%
  <-> ssub * zi4/b/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{zi4}{bx}{it}{%
  <-> ssub * zi4/b/sl}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Regular  
\textbf{Bold}
\textsl{Slanted}
\textit{Italics}
\textbf{\textsl{BoldSlanted}}
\textbf{\textit{BoldItalics}}
\end{document}
```

Finally the TFM files are needed. A poor man's solution is to use the TFM files for the original fonts. The example would need (bash syntax):

```bash
cp $(kpsewhich ot1-zi4r-0.tfm) ot1-zi4r-sl-0.tfm
cp $(kpsewhich ot1-zi4b-0.tfm) ot1-zi4b-sl-0.tfm
```

> [image: Result]

Again, the slanted and italic variants are only faked. Also the italics correction is missing, but it could be added by editing the `.tfm` files.

Comment: While I admire the technical wizardry in this answer (+1), I cannot refrain from disparaging the purpose to which it is turned. ;)

Comment: Hmm, looks like fontspec should also slant the bold font with AutoFakeSlant. [Bug added](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/172).

Comment: @cfr It should be noted that it's quite common for font designers to simply slant the glyphs for an italic monospaced font. I'd consider this less of a travesty than, say, slanting a text font.

Comment: [This one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44935/21930) might give even another option to slant a font. But haven't tried it, so it might give problems.

Comment: @Manuel: There are problems with line and page breaks inside the argument. Then the coordinate systems of TeX and the PDF output device get out of sync. Safely it can be used inside `\mbox`, which forbids line breaks.

Comment: I also needed to copy at at least `ot1-zi4r-4.tfm`, so I just copied all the `.tfm` files (from 0 through 7): `for i in {0..7}; do; cp $(kpsewhich ot1-zi4r-$i.tfm) ot1-zi4r-sl-$i.tfm; cp $(kpsewhich ot1-zi4b-$i.tfm) ot1-zi4b-sl-$i.tfm; done`.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky Thanks for the fix for the empty line in the map file.

Answer (score 4):

There are now two variants of Inconsolata that have italics (as well as bold, bold italic and Cyrillic and Greek support for all of the weights and styles).

These are [Inconsolata LGC](https://github.com/MihailJP/Inconsolata-LGC) and [Inconsolata LGC Markup](http://bdtechconcepts.com/Inconsolata-LGC-Markup-Font.html). The latter also tries to distinguish various kinds of quote and apostrophe-like characters, en/em dashes and hyphens,... It's all listed on the link.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no italic version for your font (at least not that I'm aware of), but you can always search for a monospaced font you like in the [`LaTeX Font Catalogue`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)