# How to specify non-standard font in fancyvrb Verbatim?

Tags: fonts, verbatim, fancyvrb

I am using Inconsolata for code in paragraphs, and would like to use it for code in verbatim environments as well. I have tried using fancyvrb's Verbatim environment to do this, but cannot get any font except Courier.  My document starts like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOut}{Verbatim}{fontfamily=courier}

\begin{document}

Normal paragraph with \texttt{code using texttt}.

\begin{VerbOut}
VerbOut environment.
\end{VerbOut}

\end{document}
```

1. If I change the `fontfamily` in the definition of `VerbOut` to
   `inconsolata`, the verbatim block displays the normal (Times Roman)
   font.
2. If I change it to `\sffamily`, I get an error: `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`
3. I get the same error with `{\sffamily}`, `\protect\sffamily`, and other variations.

Questions:

1. What's the right way to change the font to Inconsolata?
2. What's the right way to change it to whatever is being used by `\texttt` (in case we change our minds about fonts again)?

Answer (score 3):

The font family for [`inconsolata`](http://ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata) is actually `zi4`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOutA}{Verbatim}{fontfamily=courier}% Courier
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOutB}{Verbatim}{fontfamily=cmtt}% Computer Modern Typewriter
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOutC}{Verbatim}{fontfamily=zi4}% Inconsolata

\begin{document}

Normal paragraph with \texttt{code using texttt}.

\begin{VerbOutA}
VerbOut environment.
\end{VerbOutA}

\begin{VerbOutB}
VerbOut environment.
\end{VerbOutB}

\begin{VerbOutC}
VerbOut environment.
\end{VerbOutC}

\end{document}
```

Here is my `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
    book.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    bk10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
inconsolata.sty    2013/06/09 zi4a
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 upquote.sty    2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verbat
im
  ot1zi4.fd    2013/06/09 OT1/zi4 (Inconsolata)
  ot1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
 ***********
```

Comment: Thx for the quick reply, but still not working for me: if I set fontfamily=zi4, I'm told "Font shape `OT1/zi4/m/n' undefined" & get Times Roman, but if I \usepackage{zi4} as per http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/fonts/inconsolata/doc/inconsolata-doc.pdf, I'm told "'zi4.sty' not found". After downloading, it looks like the only diff between 'inconsolata.sty' and 'zi4.sty' is the name in the \ProvidesPackage{} decl at the top. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @GregWilson: I've added my [`\listfiles`](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X) to the post so you can see the font definitions used for `zi4`. It seems like you may have only downloaded `inconsolata.sty` and placed it in your working folder - you need the font definition files as well, properly installed. Are you compiling with pdfLaTeX? What operating system are you running? What TeX distribution? [Is your distribution up to date?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: OK, updating everything has mostly worked - thanks. Only problem now is that `zi4` doesn't seem to have italics, but that's a separate issue (?). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GregWilson: That is covered in your question: [Inconsolate italics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183204/inconsolata-italics/183220#183220)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% always a good idea
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOut}{Verbatim}{fontfamily=courier}
\begin{document}

Normal paragraph with \texttt{code using texttt}.

\begin{VerbOut}
VerbOut environment.
\end{VerbOut}

\end{document}
```

and have alook into the file list (at the end of the log file. It shows at the end the internal family name of Inconsolata:

```
*File List*
book.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
bk10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fancyvrb.sty 2011/04/06
keyval.sty 2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
fontenc.sty
t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inconsolata.sty 2013/06/09 zi4a
textcomp.sty 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
ts1cmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
upquote.sty 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verbat
im
t1zi4.fd 2013/06/09 T1/zi4 (Inconsolata)
t1pcr.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pcr.
***********
```

`t1zi4.fd` is the font definition file of Inconsolata. `t1` is the font encoding and `zi4` the family name.

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOut}{Verbatim}{fontfamily=zi4}
```

should word if you have Inconsolata installed.