# Iconsolata Bold Italics FakeSlant Not Working (Xe/LuaLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, fontspec, inconsolata

This is a follow-up question of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183220/234654), which provides a `FakeSlant`-based method for providing bold italics for Iconsolata using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (with `fontspec`).

The original method works, but when specifying `Extension = .otf`, or using `iconsolata` as the font name (because there is `inconsolata.fontspec` in the [`inconsolata-zi4` package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inconsolata-zi4)), the fake slant for bold italics fails.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% this works
% \setmonofont{Inconsolatazi4}[
%   AutoFakeSlant,
%   BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant},
% ]

% this does not work
\setmonofont[
  AutoFakeSlant,
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant},
]{inconsolata}

% this does not work either
% \setmonofont[
%   UprightFont = *-Regular,
%   BoldFont = *-Bold,
%   AutoFakeSlant,
%   BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant},
%   Extension=.otf
% ]{Inconsolatazi4}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Regular
\textbf{Bold}
\textsl{Slanted}
\textit{Italics}
\textbf{\textsl{BoldSlanted}}
\textbf{\textit{BoldItalics}}
\end{document}
```

Not Working:

[image: not working]

Working:

[image: working]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inconsolatea has no Italics so it fallbacks to slanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

 \setmonofont[
   UprightFont = *-Regular,
   BoldFont = *-Bold,
   SlantedFont = *-Regular,
   SlantedFeatures = {FakeSlant=0.2},
   BoldSlantedFont = *-Bold,
   BoldSlantedFeatures = {FakeSlant=0.2,RawFeature={embolden=2}},
   Extension=.otf
 ]{Inconsolatazi4}

\begin{document}
    \ttfamily
    Regular
    \textbf{Bold}
    \textsl{Slanted}
    \textit{Italics}
    \textbf{\textsl{BoldSlanted}}
    \textbf{\textit{BoldItalics}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! Indeed, using `BoldSlantedFeatures` in addition to `BoldItalicFeatures` will address the issue, and also stop the warning of fallback.