# Blackboard slanted type1

Tags: math-mode, blackboard, slanted

The answer to
[this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44934/free-non-upright-blackboard-type1-font) is cool. One minor issue is that superscripts seem too close:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\fakeslant[1]{%
  \pdfliteral{1 0 0.167 1 0 0 cm}#1\pdfliteral{1 0 -0.167 1 0 0 cm}}
\newcommand\mathbbsl[1]{\mathbb{\fakeslant{#1}}}
\begin{document}

$\mathbbsl{M}'\mathbbsl{M}^*\mathbbsl{M}^\dagger$

\end{document}
```

[image: result of the above latex code]

Can this be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add an extra `\hspace`, and combine it to a new command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\fakeslant[1]{%
  \pdfliteral{1 0 0.167 1 0 0 cm}#1\pdfliteral{1 0 -0.167 1 0 0 cm}}
\newcommand\mathbbsl[1]{\mathbb{\fakeslant{#1}}}
\newcommand{\iwd}[3][0.01cm]{\mathbbsl{#2}\hspace*{#1}{#3}}

\begin{document}

$\iwd{M}{^*}$
$\iwd[0.02cm]{M}{^*}$
$\iwd[0.03cm]{M}{^*}$
$\iwd[0.04cm]{M}{^*}$
$\iwd[0.05cm]{M}{^*}$

$\iwd{M}{'}$
$\iwd[0.02cm]{M}{'}$
$\iwd[0.03cm]{M}{'}$
$\iwd[0.04cm]{M}{'}$
$\iwd[0.05cm]{M}{'}$


$\iwd{M}{^\dagger}$
$\iwd[0.02cm]{M}{^\dagger}$
$\iwd[0.03cm]{M}{^\dagger}$
$\iwd[0.04cm]{M}{^\dagger}$
$\iwd[0.05cm]{M}{^\dagger}$



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be much better to use a math space and `mu` units (or at least a font dependent space) rather than a fixed unit like `cm` so that it works naturally after a font size change such as \small or \large