# How to make double-struck capital letters italic (e.g. U+1D53C)?

Tags: math-mode, italic, mathjax

In Word I am able to include the unicode symbol U+1D53C (write number and press Alt+C) and assign **italic formatting**:

[image: italic output]

How do I get the same result in LaTeX?

I tried:

1. `\mathit{\mathbb{E}}`
2. `{\it \mathbb{E}}`
3. `\mathit{ \unicode{x1D7D9} \; \unicode{x1D53C}}`

I still get non-italic results:

[image: non-italic output]

Furthermore, the following examples are all non-italic for blackboard bold fonts:
[What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode#58124)

How can I slant the content of math mode? Apply some graphical transformation?

I would like to avoid extra definitions in my preamble.

Comment: Just found this related question (the solution given there does not seem to work in asciidoctor) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16645/blackboard-italic-font

Comment: asciidoctor seems to use MathJax not TeX (https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-latex#introduction)

Comment: That's just a geometric transformation performed by the software. Slanting *can* be done also with TeX, of course.

Comment: @egreg How can I slant in math mode?

Comment: I’m not seeing how a question about a math symbol is off-topic. And I can’t answer unless it’s opened.

Comment: Sorry to answer in a comment, but your question was closed. The `unicode-math` package defines a `\mathbbit` alphabet, but it covers only ⅅⅆⅇⅈⅉ. If you want the rest of the letters, find a double-struck italic font you like, declare it as `\bbitfont`, then `\newcommand\varbbit[1]{\mathord{\text{\bbitfont {#1}}}}`.

Comment: I removed the additional information that seems to be off-topic. ;)

Comment: The reason for the off-topic votes is that the question is about asciidoctor and therefore it is about MathJax. Although it is not stated explicitly in the help center, MathJax questions are generally considered off-topic. The reason is that it is a different system than LaTeX, which means that solutions for LaTeX often do not work for MathJax (as you noticed with the related question), making the question out of scope. You could try reposting it at Stack Overflow, make sure you clearly describe the context (use case, asciidoctor, web interface, JavaScript).

Comment: Well, I hoped that there would be an alternative solution that would work both with Tex and MathJax and without extra definitions, e.g. (pseudo code) \transform[slant:30°]{...} or whatever. In my opinion the issue is still valid for Latex.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why does the LaTeX mention  that is U+1D7D9, but then it does not appear in the result image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command for this in `unicode-math` is `\mathbbit` or `\symbbit`. It only supports the handful of letters defined in Unicode.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. It can also be done by faking slant also with `pdflatex`, but this would need a whole set of virtual fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfontface{\slantedmath}{Latin Modern Math}[FakeSlant=0.25]

\begin{document}

$ \slantedmath{}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In `pdflatex`, borrowing from [Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.3]
  {%
    \mbox
      {%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
      }%
  }
\begin{document}
$\slantbox{$\mathbb{E}$} = mc^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code is the same… it doesn't double-strike the char

Comment: In the context of the question @juanfal, "double struck" refers to the font type as shown in the letter `E` in my answer.  My code does not double strike the letter, `\mathbb{E}` is "double struck" to begin with.  What my code does is to convert an upright letter into an slanted (faux italic) letter.